# Swift 2 ( executeFetchRequest ) : error handling

Tags: swift, swift2

I got some issue with the code that I can't figure out. After I installed Xcode 7 beta and convert my swift code to Swift 2

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PlayerList")

    list = Context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As of Swift 2, Cocoa methods that produce errors are translated to Swift functions that throw an error.

Instead of an optional return value and an error parameter as in **Swift 1.x**:

```
var error : NSError?
if let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) {
    // success ...
    list = result
} else {
    // failure
    println("Fetch failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

in **Swift 2** the method now returns a non-optional and throws an error
in the error case, which must be handled with try-catch:

```
do {
    list = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    // success ...
} catch let error as NSError {
    // failure
    print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

For more information, see "Error Handling" in ["Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)
in the ["Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) documentation.

Comment: And if you are trying to use an array filled with custom values, your fetch line will look like this... `ideas = try self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Ideas]`

Comment: If I only have an instance of `list` and not an array for it, how do I do so?

Comment: @jo3birdtalk: executeFetchRequest() always returns an array. If there is only one instance then you can access it e.g. via `list[0]` or `list.first` .

Answer (score 4):

You could try this code:

```
let  result = (try! self.manageContext.executeFetchRequest(FetchRequest)) as! [NSManageObjectClass]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**
In this example **PlayerList** is **NSManagedObject** entity/class name (auto created by Xcode)

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<PlayerList> = PlayerList.fetchRequest()

var result:[PlayerList]?
do{
      //Succes 
      result = try context.fetch(request)
   }catch let error as NSError {
      //Error 
      print("Error \(error)")
  }

print("result: \(result)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = [YourEntity]?
results = try! self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [YourEntity]
```

Comment: Hi, If I do not have an array of `YourEntity` but an instance of it only, how I do so? I tried without the braces, it keeps prompting me that cannot convert AnyObject to type 'User'

Comment: @jo3birdtalk Just do let myResult = results?.first. If you know that your fetch request should return just one object, this is how you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Users")
        do {
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            itemList = results as! [NSManagedObject]


        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


    }
```

Comment: In general I would recommend you to add a brief description in addition to any code that you post. (So that, for example if there would be a typo, or if people are not in the opportunitiy to try it directly, people can still get the point easily).