# iOS Result type 'Element' does not match expected type (Swift - Coredata)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Using Xcode 7.0 and Swift 2

I am trying to execute a fetchrequest in CoreData but is not working.

Getting the below error. Not sure what the issue is. "segmentedControl" is an outlet from a segmentedControl view.

[image]

The strange bit is that I have used similar code in another sample project and there were no issues. Below is that code snippet

[image]

I have used the execute fetchrequest syntax based on 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954722/swift-2-executefetchrequest-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use breakpoints or print statements to examine the value of `firstTitle!`. If it is not a string, and `title` in your entity is not defined as a `String` type, you will get this error.

Also, make sure that your segmented control is set up as expected.