# How do I get the error message in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, try-catch, swift2

I used this method very much in Swift 1.2: `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(:_:_:_)` but this is apparently deprecated in iOS9. It still works however but now it uses the new Swift 2.0 Error Handling and I don't know how I will get the error message if it fails, ex. if time runs out.

I know I have to put it into a do-catch and then say try before the metho but I dont know how to catch the error message.

```
do {
    let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    return data 
}
catch _ {
    return nil
}
```

Before I used NSError and then its description property, but now I have no clue.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use automatic `error` variable, and you can cast it to `NSError` if you wish:

```
catch {
    let nsError = error as NSError
    print(nsError.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: @redent84: Any ErrorType is bridged to NSError automatically, that is documented in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book.

Comment: Or simply `catch let error as NSError { ...}` as in (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954722/swift-2-executefetchrequest-error-handling.

Comment: Thanks I didnt see any info that the error is passed like that, I only found several catches that took a specific error or none at all. I can accept in 3 min

Comment: You'll get some standard `localizedDescription` for Swift-only `ErrorType`.

Comment: There is default `localizedDescription` for any `Error` now (see link). But from my tests it seems that it simply does `let nsError = error as NSError` for us. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error/2292912-localizeddescription.

Answer (score 4):

You can now throw any object inheriting `ErrorType`, and provide custom handling in the `catch` sentence. You can also cast the error to `NSError` to access `localizedDescription` for handling third party errors.

Casting an enum `ErrorType` will produce a `NSError` with `domain` equal to the enum name, `code` equal to the enum value and an auto-generated `localizedDescription` with the following format:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (DOMAIN error CODE.)

For example, the following code:

```
enum AwfulError: ErrorType {
    case Bad
    case Worse
    case Terrible
}

func throwingFunction() throws {
    throw AwfulError.Worse
}

do {
    try throwingFunction()
}
catch AwfulError.Bad {
    print("Bad error")
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Will print

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (AwfulError error 1.)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the question title specifying Swift 2, this answer is for Swift 3.

As @redent84 points out, since Swift 2 an Error object may be a home-made one. Here's a method I wrote to analyze and print the default error object available in a "catch" statement that doesn't specify any specific error type:

```
   // Method to print an unknown Error type object to the system output.
   static func printCaughtError(_ unknownError : Error) {
      let objectDescription = String(describing: unknownError)
      let localizedDescription = unknownError.localizedDescription
      if localizedDescription != "" {
         if localizedDescription.contains(objectDescription) {
            print(localizedDescription)
            return
         }
         if !objectDescription.contains(localizedDescription) {
            print(objectDescription + ": " + localizedDescription)
            return
         }
      }
      print(objectDescription)
   }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
    catch {
       printCaughtError(error)
    }
```

Comment: You can implement this as an extension on `Error`, this way you get fluent API :)

Answer (score 0):

How to get the error **message** that is inside **userInfo**:

```
let errorMessage = (error as NSError).userInfo["message"] as? String
```