# Core data error handling

Tags: core-data, swift2

Playing with core data and got stuck with this in Swift 2.0

```
var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
       error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]
```

Xcode error says "Extra argument in call" and when I remove `error:&error` it says "error not handled", so what's the new syntax?

Comment: You can find the answer in the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954722/swift-2-executefetchrequest-error-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2.0 you have to use exception handling:

```
var fetchedResults : [NSManagedObject]?

do {
    fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)