# CoreData , executeFetchRequest, Extra Argument "Error" in Call

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vyzdrjlpvdcuill/managedContext.png?dl=0

I had this working January and when I ran it today, I was presented with this error. 
I have tried to understand the new method of error handling, sadly I am not grasping it. 
first time poster.
Sincerely,
rob

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30954753/3985749)

Comment: In January you wouldn't have been using Swift 2. Things have changed. :)

Comment: A few things have changed and I am trying to adapt to the changes, Strangely I am trying and I find Objective C allot easier than Swift. There are allot of things which has been simplified in Swift and I am appreciating the simplicity. I will try and work things out with the example that was given above. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You have extra argument, which is the error,

Simple remove it.

Also this is a working code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "movieQuoteEntityName")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastTouchDate", ascending: false)]
        var error :NSError? = nil
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
        let movieQuotes = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
```

Comment: I am trying it right now. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the Swift 2.0, they changed the whole error handling stuff so you are not able to declare that way. 
Swift has try-catch now for the error handling, so you may change all of the old error handling methods.