# Why is this Label not showing the correct value? Swift

Tags: swift, function, label

I wrote a code to take data from my CoreDate Entity to show the highest Integer as the value at a Highscore label. I don't understand why it is not working? I tried it with or without a extra function...

```
func loadHighscore() {
        
        //Kontext identifizieren
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        
        //Anfrage stellen
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entityName = "PushUps"
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        
        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(request)
            for result in results {
            
                guard let count = (result as! NSManagedObject).value(forKey: "highScore") as? Int16 else {
                        return
        
                    }
            }
                if count > highScore {
                    highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(count)"
                    highScoreChanged(newHighScore: Int16(count))
                    // Console statement:
                    print("New Highscore: \(count)")
                }
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        
    }
    
    
    func highScoreChanged(newHighScore: Int16) {
        highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(newHighScore)"
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: 1. Print out an error code like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40186770/1040347 and updlate your question. 2. What database structure do you have? PushUps exists?

Comment: Move your if statement outside of your do catch statement. Let the Core Data run first.

Comment: @dscrown That is completely irrelevant and wouldn't make for any improvement

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Yes it exists, all the print Statements are shown in the console when I run the App but for inexplicable reasons it doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is a bit strange.

A better approach is to load the data sorted descending by `highScore` so the first item is the item with the highest value.

It's highly recommended to take advantage of the generic Core Data types and to use dot notation rather the KVC `value(forKey`

```
func loadHighscore() {
    
    //Kontext identifizieren
    // delegate can be forced unwrapped. The app doesn't even launch if AppDelegate doesn't exist
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    //Anfrage stellen
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entityName = "PushUps"
    
    // Use a specific fetch request
    let request = NSFetchRequest<PushUps>(entityName: entityName)
    // add a sort descriptor to sort the items by highScore descending
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "highScore", ascending: false)]
    
    do {
        // results is an array of PushUps instances, no type cast needed
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if let result = results.first, result.highScore > highScore {
            highScore = result.highScore
            print("New Highscore: \(highScore)")
        } 
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: \(highScore)"
}
```

The function `highScoreChanged` is not needed either. If the saved highscore is higher than the current value (property `highScore`) the property is updated and at the end of the method the text field is updated with the value of the property `highScore`.

Comment: Great thank you! I have started learning how to code in the beginning of corona and sometimes I'm really on my limit and have no idea what to do :( Do you have any advice how to make bigger progress?

Comment: Lesen, lesen, lesen. (Read, read, read). Treat programming like a foreign language. For example read the Apple Programming Guides and the Swift Language Guide

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to execute the label update in main queue. In other way it may not be done.

Comment: there is no need, `viewContext` already fetches on a [main queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640622-viewcontext)